# vb.net select statement failing

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have this code to populate a DataGridView (DGV) the goal is to only populate the DGV with data from the LinkTable where one of its fields ytSiteType is equal to a global variable set on another form. The variable is gvSLT and I have tested that gvSLT makes the trip to the new form with the correct value.
I have solved the problem by adding an If statement to the SQLiteDataReader routine.
I will post the code below with these two line of code that fail.

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM LinkTable WHERE ytSiteType =" & gvSLT
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM LinkTable WHERE ytSiteType = 'gvSLT'"
```

Here is the the code that is working

```
        Using conn As New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;")
        conn.Open()

        Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand("", conn)

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM LinkTable"
            'cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM LinkTable WHERE ytSiteType =" & gvSLT
            'cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM LinkTable WHERE ytSiteType = 'gvSLT'"
            'cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM LinkTable WHERE ytSiteType = 'News'"

            Using rdr As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                'dgvLinks.DataSource = rdr
                'Statement Above use when DB is bound to dgvLinks
                '=================================================

                While rdr.Read()
                    intID = CInt((rdr("LID")))
                    strChannelName = rdr("ytChannelName").ToString
                    strLinkAddress = rdr("ytLinkAddress").ToString
                    strLinkType = rdr("ytSiteType").ToString
                    If strLinkType = gvSLT Then
                        dgvLinks.Rows.Add(intID, strChannelName, strLinkAddress)
                        rowCount = rowCount + 1
                    End If
                End While

            End Using
```

**The question is "Why are the commented out SELECT statements failing"**

Comment: What is the datatype of the database field named _ytSiteType_? However this is a classic problem that should never happen if you start to use parameters when you build your sql command texts.

Comment: @Steve ytSiteType is a TEXT when I create the table So replace cmd.CommandText with  cmd.Parameters but what comes after  cmd.Parameters ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example fails because, if *ytSiteType* is a field of string type, you are concatenating the value of *gvSLT* without putting it inside single quotes.

The second example fails because you are putting inside single quotes the literal text "gvSLT" not the value of *gvSLT*.

The third example, I am not sure, but probably fails because there is no record with exactly the "News" value.

You should always use parameters to avoid these problems and others like SqlInjection, parsing decimal separator in numeric values and problems if the input *gvSLT* contains itself one or more single quotes.

So a simple solution should be:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM LinkTable WHERE ytSiteType = @site"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@site", DbType.String).Value = gvSLT
```

Comment: the Third example actual works I will swear I tried the AT gvSLT concept but that is just the same issue even though gvSLT is a declared as a String Let me test Thanks Tested Code and it works I assume AT site is a variable you added

Comment: `@site` is not a variable. It is what is called a parameter placeholder. The database engine recognizes these placeholders and build a suitable query using the informations present in the parameter with the same name added to the command Parameters collection.